# How to decrypt an encrypted message using metamask?

Tags: web3js, metamask

I have a message encrypted with the public key. Metamask has its corresponding private key (account). How can I decrypt it with the metamask? Does metamask provide such feature?

What I meant is just like while performing the **web3.eth.sign** function, metamask provides us the window to sign a message does it also provide some functionality to decrypt a message?

In my application server stores a code (text) encrypted with user's public key. In the client side (javascript) user first needs to decrypt this code to do some task. So, either I prompt user to enter its private key (which is considered a bad practice) or I use some wallet or account management like Metamask.

Please suggest.

Comment: Metamask does not have a feature for what you've described. Maybe provide more context :) ?

Answer (score 6):

Looks like Metamask added functionality for [this](https://github.com/MetaMask/eth-simple-keyring).

You can use their following API commands:
`getEncryptionPublicKey(address)` & `decryptMessage(address, data)`

Answer (score 3):

Currently, Metamask doesn't provide any such functionality. A discussion is going on to make some relative update. You can stay tuned: https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/1190