# Web3.js to decode encrypted data using my private key

Tags: web3js, metamask

It's very similar to this question: [How to decrypt an encrypted message using metamask?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/49321/how-to-decrypt-an-encrypted-message-using-metamask) who was put one year ago.

As user, I would like to store data safely on the blockchain, data that I want to retrieve easily and decode locally. It seems that such feature was planned on web3.js 1.0 but I did not see anything on it.....

Answer (score 2):

There is no such functionality in web3js (yet), but this answer ( [Encrypt data using public key](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/61181/encrypt-data-using-public-key) ) may help if you are looking for some way to do it, apart from web3js